# What strategies are available to me to add variables to Request.ServerVariables

Tags: c#, iis

What methods are available to me if I want to add an IIS Server Variable to Request.ServerVariables?  I'd like to add a value to it before an application starts to pass a variable to that web application.  Can a HttpHandler manage it?

Comment: Have you looked at Application_Start in Global.asax.cs? That would allow you to pass info into the web app.

Comment: The target web application doesn't have source code available for us to modify.  That's why I need to modify the ServerVariables.

Answer (score 0):

`Request.ServerVariables` is really old stuff for compatibility with Classic ASP. You should find another way to do this. What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: Are you sure about that?  A lot of Single Sign On solutions work by authenticating a user and then adding the authentication information to the IIS Server Variables.

Comment: Name one, and how hold is it? Is it using isapi? If so, then it's a bit old.

Comment: And you didn't say what you're trying to accomplish, so I can't tell you that an `HttpModule` will likely accomplish it. You didn't even say what version of IIS you're running, so I can't tell you that the `HttpModule` will work for all types of content if you're using IIS7.